# "HydraVision Desktop Manager is already running"

Tags: login, amd-radeon, fast-user-switching

On my Windows 7 machine when I use the switch user option to log in as a second user I get a message box with the message "HydraVision Desktop Manager is already running". Everything works fine after this. I have the latest AMD drivers installed. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HydraVision has some problems when working in multi-user environments. It's probably trying to start it, while it's already running from the previous user's session.

If you do not need HydraVision, I advise you to run the AMD uninstaller and choose to uninstall HydraVision while keeping the other components.

If you do need it, try disabling HydraVision from running at the start-up and run it manually.